# Keep all indexes in multilevel pandas groupby

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing, pandas-groupby

I have the following data frame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1.1, 1.1, 1.1, 2.6, 2.5, 3.4,2.6,2.6,3.4,3.4,2.6,1.1,1.1,3.3], list('AAABBBBABCBDDD'), [1.1, 1.7, 2.5, 2.6, 3.3, 3.8,4.0,4.2,4.3,4.5,4.6,4.7,4.7,4.8], ['1','3','3','2','4','2','5','3','6','3','5','1','1','1']]).T
df.columns = ['col1','col2','col3','col4']
```

When I group it I get:

```
df.groupby(['col4','col2']).sum()

           col1  col3
col4 col2            
1    A      1.1   1.1
     D      5.5  14.2
2    B      6.0   6.4
3    A      4.8   8.4
     C      3.4   4.5
4    B      2.5   3.3
5    B      5.2   8.6
6    B      3.4   4.3
```

However what I would like to have is the same second level index for each first level index. This is not possible because of missing data. What I would like to achieve is:

```
           col1  col3
col4 col2            
1    A      1.1   1.1
     B      0     0
     C      0     0
     D      5.5  14.2
2    A      0     0
     B      6.0   6.4
     C      0     0
     D      0     0
3    A      4.8   8.4
     B      0     0
     C      3.4   4.5
     D      0     0
4    A      0     0
     B      2.5   3.3
     C      0     0
     D      0     0
5    A      0     0
     B      5.2   8.6
     C      0     0
     D      0     0
6    A      0     0
     B      3.4   4.3
     C      0     0
     D      0     0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could create a new `MultiIndex` from your data, and `reindex`, like this.

```
In [6]: idx = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([df.col4.unique(), df.col2.unique()])

In [9]: (df.groupby(['col4','col2']).sum()
           .reindex(idx).fillna(0))
Out[9]: 
     col1  col3
1 A   1.1   1.1
  B   0.0   0.0
  C   0.0   0.0
  D   5.5  14.2
3 A   4.8   8.4
  B   0.0   0.0
  C   3.4   4.5
  D   0.0   0.0
2 A   0.0   0.0
  B   6.0   6.4
  C   0.0   0.0
  D   0.0   0.0
4 A   0.0   0.0
  B   2.5   3.3
  C   0.0   0.0
  D   0.0   0.0
5 A   0.0   0.0
  B   5.2   8.6
  C   0.0   0.0
  D   0.0   0.0
6 A   0.0   0.0
  B   3.4   4.3
  C   0.0   0.0
  D   0.0   0.0
```

Answer (score 2):

To account for the missing indices, you'll probably need to reindex the DataFrame returned by `df.groupby(['col4','col2']).sum()`:

```
>>> m = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([df.col4.unique(), df.col2.unique()])
>>> df.groupby(['col4','col2']).sum().reindex(m, fill_value=0)

     col1  col3
1 A   1.1   1.1
  B   0.0   0.0
  C   0.0   0.0
  D   5.5  14.2
3 A   4.8   8.4
  B   0.0   0.0
  C   3.4   4.5
  D   0.0   0.0
2 A   0.0   0.0
  B   6.0   6.4
  C   0.0   0.0
  D   0.0   0.0
4 A   0.0   0.0
  B   2.5   3.3
  C   0.0   0.0
  D   0.0   0.0
5 A   0.0   0.0
  B   5.2   8.6
  C   0.0   0.0
  D   0.0   0.0
6 A   0.0   0.0
  B   3.4   4.3
  C   0.0   0.0
  D   0.0   0.0
```

Note that `unique()` returns the values in the order they appear in the column (e.g. '3' appears before '2' here). You could correct this by using `.sortlevel(0)` on the reindexed DataFrame.